# Is SSL required to use the google plus api?

Tags: oauth, google-plus

Im fairly new to Oauth2.0.
I wanted to start using the Google Plus api.

**I used the following resources**

> "[Using OAuth 2.0 to Access Google APIs](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth2.html)" documentation.
>
> [Google Plus Oauth Api](http://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth) scope key
>   (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me).

After playing with curl and having success with other "scope keys" . I encountered the following error with the google plus scope (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me).

**"Token invalid - AuthSub token has wrong scope"**

Then i found the solution [Google’s OAuth Pain: Token invalid – AuthSub token has wrong scope](http://www.geoffmcqueen.com/2010/03/14/token-invalid-authsub-token-has-wrong-scope-oauth-google-problem/)

It pointed out the **following**:

> if you’re getting a “Token Invalid – AuthSub token has wrong scope”
>   error when you’re trying to use OAuth (or even AuthSub for that
>   matter?), make sure the scope you’re requesting is using the same
>   protocol as you’re using

I did what he said , took the "s" off the scope "

```
http://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me
```

But now it gives me this error

[image]

**Does this mean that your site MUST use SSL?**

Thanks for the feedback.

**EDIT: Turns out i was using the wrong api**
Should be https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?access_token=xxxx

Comment: The Google+ API endpoint is `https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/`. Google's OAuth2 Authorization Endpoint is `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth`. I don't see any non-HTTPS URI anywhere.

Comment: Yeah, using the HTTPS version resulted in, "Token invalid - AuthSub token has wrong scope" as pointed above

Comment: Can you add steps to reproduce the problem?

Comment: I think i found the issue. My last curl statement, il post the answer in a min.

Comment: Had the wrong URL in using my access_token

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer, i was using the wrong url for the api

**https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me**?access_token={hash}

Comment: Is that 'blah' the oauth_token recieved in your callback url, or is it an access token generated from the validator and request token?

Comment: blah is the temporary hash you are granted. You use your
[client_id, client_secret, code (authorization_code)] to retrieve it. Posting those to https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token returns your access token

Answer (score 7):

Your site doesn't need to use SSL but all calls it makes to the Google+ API must use HTTPS. See: http://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth for more information about OAuth scopes in Google+